# How to display automatically computed value on input type number?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning JavaScript in Scrimba and there is a practice part where to make a unit conversion but I already did the static one then I challenge myself to add an user input but I just burnout my self I'm so confused now

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="unit">
            <h2 id="heading">Metric/Imperial Unit Converstion</h2>
            <!-- <h2 id="numToConvert"> 0 </h2> -->
            <input type="number" value="num" id="inputNum" min="0" onchange="unitConvert()">
            
        </div>
    </main>
    <section> 
        <div class="main-results"> 
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Length (Meter/Feet)
                <p id="meterFeet">0 meters = 0.000 feet | 0 feet = 0.000 meters</p>
            </div>
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Volumes (Liters/Gallons)
                <p id="litersGallons">0 liters = 0.000 gallons | 0 gallons = 0.000 liters</p>
            </div>
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Mass (Kilograns/Pounds)
                <p id="kiloPounds">0 kilos = 0.000 pounds | 0 pounds = 0.000 kilos</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
const unit = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;

function unitConvert() {
    const meterToFeet = (unit * 3.28084).toFixed(3)
    const feetToMeter = (unit * 0.3048).toFixed(3)

    const litersToGallons = (unit * 0.264172).toFixed(3)
    const GallonsToLiters = (unit * 3.785412).toFixed(3)

    const kilogramsToPounds = (unit * 2.2).toFixed(3)
    const poundsToKilograms = (unit / 2.2).toFixed(3)

    //Meter to Feet/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("meterFeet").textContent = unit +" meters = "+ meterToFeet +" feet | "+unit+" feet = "+feetToMeter+" meters"
    //Liters to Gallons/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("litersGallons").textContent = unit +" liters = "+ litersToGallons +" gallons | "+unit+" gallons = "+GallonsToLiters+" liters"
    //Kilo to Pounds/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("kiloPounds").textContent = unit +" kilos = "+ kilogramsToPounds +" pounds | "+unit+" pounds = "+poundsToKilograms+" kilos"
}
```

Comment: try adding a listener. as you type listener will be called and it listener will call the `unitConvert` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code i hope it is what you asked for

```js
function unitConvert() {


    const unit = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
    const meterToFeet = (unit * 3.28084).toFixed(3)
    const feetToMeter = (unit * 0.3048).toFixed(3)

    const litersToGallons = (unit * 0.264172).toFixed(3)
    const GallonsToLiters = (unit * 3.785412).toFixed(3)

    const kilogramsToPounds = (unit * 2.2).toFixed(3)
    const poundsToKilograms = (unit / 2.2).toFixed(3)

    //Meter to Feet/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("meterFeet").textContent = unit +" meters = "+ meterToFeet +" feet | "+unit+" feet = "+feetToMeter+" meters"
    //Liters to Gallons/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("litersGallons").textContent = unit +" liters = "+ litersToGallons +" gallons | "+unit+" gallons = "+GallonsToLiters+" liters"
    //Kilo to Pounds/Vice Versa
    document.getElementById("kiloPounds").textContent = unit +" kilos = "+ kilogramsToPounds +" pounds | "+unit+" pounds = "+poundsToKilograms+" kilos"
}

const inputField = document.querySelector('#inputNum');
inputField .addEventListener('input', function () {
  unitConvert()
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: #fcbe24;
  background-color: #18222d;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="unit">
            <h2 id="heading">Metric/Imperial Unit Converstion</h2>
            <!-- <h2 id="numToConvert"> 0 </h2> -->
            <input type="number" value="num" id="inputNum" min="0" onchange="unitConvert()">
            
        </div>
    </main>
    <section> 
        <div class="main-results"> 
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Length (Meter/Feet)
                <p id="meterFeet">0 meters = 0.000 feet | 0 feet = 0.000 meters</p>
            </div>
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Volumes (Liters/Gallons)
                <p id="litersGallons">0 liters = 0.000 gallons | 0 gallons = 0.000 liters</p>
            </div>
            <div class="conversion-results">
                <p>Mass (Kilograns/Pounds)
                <p id="kiloPounds">0 kilos = 0.000 pounds | 0 pounds = 0.000 kilos</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you bro, it worked! I need to practice more hehe thank you!